# How to ignore whitespaces in cin but only after the first whitespace? (c++)

Tags: c++, cin, getline

So I'm making a text adventure which involves a user entering a command and then the name of an item.

Here is the relevant section of my code

```
string input1, input2, input3;

cout << "-------------\nWhat would you like to do?\n------------" << endl;
cin >> input1 >> input2;


if (input1 == "use") // Use command
{
    cout << "Use " << input2 << "?\n"; 
    use(input2);
}

void use(string item1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) // Is item1 in inventory?
    {
        if (itemlist[i][0] == item1)     // checks typed name against possible item names
        {
            if (itemlist[i][1] == "yes")  // checks if that item is in player inventory
            {
                 //Do thing
            }
        }
    }
}
```

All the items in the game and their details are held in a string array with the name `itemlist`.

`itemlist[i][0]` holds each items name, often a multiple word name with spaces like "sulphuric acid"

My question is regarding the line

```
cin >> input1 >> input2;
```

`input1` being the action, and `input2` being the item. `input1` is always a single word string, but `input2` is sometimes a multi word string.

So if the user was to input "use starting room key", it takes "use" as `input1` as it should, but rather than taking "starting room key" as `input2`, it just takes "starting" as `input2`, and so when it checks `input2` against `itemlist[i][0]` it doesn't match.

Is there a way to have whitespaces be ignored in the cin, but only after `input1`?

My alternative would be to have the action entered and then on the next like the item name and then use getline, but that's not ideal really.

Comment: How about reading the second string using `std::getline`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Figured out the answer with more google based on what you said, ended up using getline(cin >> input1 >> ws, input2); instead of my cin >> input1 >> input2. Works perfectly. Thanks for your input.